# How do I make a node.js TCP connection reconnect automatically?

Tags: node.js, tcp, client-server

I wrote a TCP client and server in node.js. I can't figure out how to make client reconnect when it disconnects for any reason whatsoever. I understand I have to handle `'close'` event, but it's an event that gets fired only when connection gracefully closes. I don't know how to handle network errors when connection just ends because of network issues.

Here's the code that I've so far:

```
function connect () {
  client = new net.Socket();
  client.connect(config.port, config.host, function () {
    console.log('connected to server');
  });

  client.on('close', function () {
    console.log('dis-connected from server');
    connect();
  });

  client.on('error', ...); // what do I do with this?
  client.on('timeout', ...); // what is this event? I don't understand
}
```

Can anyone explain what do I do in `error` and `timeout` case? And how do I know that the network has disconnected and reconnect?

Comment: you can use this plugin https://github.com/alexkwolfe/node-eversocket or inspect how it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably just leave the `error` event handler as a no-op/empty function, unless you want to also log the error or something useful. The `close` event for TCP sockets is always emitted, even after `error`, so that is why you can ignore it.

Also, [`close`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/net.html#net_event_close_1) event handlers are passed a boolean `had_error` argument that indicates whether the socket close was due to error and not a normal connection teardown.

The [`timeout`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/net.html#net_event_timeout) event is for detecting a loss of traffic between the two endpoints (the timeout used is set with [`socket.setTimeout()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/net.html#net_socket_settimeout_timeout_callback).

Comment: So I think I should only be handling 'close' event, right?

Comment: Handle `close` too like I mentioned, otherwise you will get uncaught exceptions when `error` (e.g. ECONNRESET) is emitted.